# Unable to create spanning tree with the given diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I've been trying to figure out this question, but no matter how many times I try to answer the question, the end result will always be a circuit. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is a "simple circuit"?

Comment: If you simply trace out the vertices in alphabetical order, you’re following the edges of a spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the edges in $(a,b,j,f,g,h,a)$ and $(c,d,e,j,c)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just remove one simple circuit to end with a spanning tree, you could remove abcdefjigha